# Как перевести число в массив цифр на Си?

Tags: c, массивы

Как перевести число в массив цифр на Си?

Comment: Здесь посмотри http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread154079.html

Answer (score 4):

Непонятно, что вы хотите...

Если цифры - это символы, то массив получается как

```
char digs[20];
sprintf(digs,"%d",n);
```

Если имеется в виду массив чисел - типа

```
int array[20] = {0};
```

то вариант такой:

```
for(int i = 19; n; n/=10) array[i--] = n%10;
```

Если и это не то, что вам нужно - поясните тогда понятнее, что вам надо.

Comment: Второй вариант может быть из первого получен путём `for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) digs[i] -= '0';`

Comment: @0andriy Может, только тогда это не `int`, а еще у вас ряд элементов окажется равен -48...

Comment: Какой смысл в int для цифр? Во втором вы правы, надо добавить проверку на \0. Всяко быстрее, чем деления.

Comment: @0andriy Никак не соображу, а как получить строку - как ее делает `sprintf` - без деления? Если не трудно, подскажите алгоритм...

Comment: @Mikhailo, например, как это сделано в Linux kernel: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L134. Если интересна эта тема, то вот есть исследование французов https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00864293v1/document. Ищите, да обрящите ;)

Comment: @0andriy Спасибо!